# Setting default download directory Selenium ChromeDriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I see this question has been answered several times before but none of the solutions appear to be working anymore.

My script looks like:

```
from selenium import webdriver
chromeoptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"download.default_directory" : "/root/path/to/folder"}
chromeoptions.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chromeoptions)
```

Everything is working as normal...but the download directory reset fails silently.

I have tested the rest of the code (but not the download directory reset) on Windows and it is working correctly, other similar scripts (without the download) are working normally too. The chromeoptions object is also correctly showing the target directory under experimental options...so it is presumably being passed to the browser object.

Something is going wrong, I am not sure what? I am using Python 2.7, latest versions of Chrome/Selenium/ChromeDriver on Ubuntu 14.